# Integrating Cardmagic gem in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to rails platform. I am developing a simple applicatoin in which I want to import all my gmail contacts. I Came to know that I can use cardmagic gem for importing contacts. It is given  on link below.

https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts.git

I want to know how to integrate it in my application.I am trying to install it using

```
 gem install contact
```

Then I did

```
bundle install
```

&

```
bundle update
```

Both commands executed without error still am not getting whether the gem is installed or not.I checked **gemfile** to check its entry.It is not there.
Please guide me whether I am going right or not & also tell me how can I use its functionality.
Please also tell me about good resources that will elaborate more about gems & their uses.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bundler, you need to add the gem to your Gemfile, and not install it with `gem install contact`.

If you look at the [RubyGems page for contacts](https://rubygems.org/gems/contacts) you can see how they recommend adding it:

```
gem "contacts", "~> 1.2.4"
```

Once it's in your Gemfile, just run `bundle` from within your application directory and it will install it.